# Using jBehave with Java, how can I chain jQuery methods in a selector

Tags: jquery, jbehave

I want to select the edit button within a table for the row containing the text "Take these Directions".

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-element="content">Default Directions</td>
    <td data-element="action">
      <a class="btn" title="Edit"><i class=icon icon-edit"></i></a>
      <a class="btn" title="Delete"><i class=icon icon-delete"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-element="content">Take these Directions</td>
    <td data-element="action">
      <a class="btn" title="Edit"><i class=icon icon-edit"></i></a>
      <a class="btn" title="Delete"><i class=icon icon-delete"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Normally, I would use a chained jQuery like this:

```js
$("td[data-element='content']:contains('Take these Directions')").parent().find("a[title='Edit']")
```

But I seem to be allowed to only use a single jQuery string, not a chain of methods. Any suggestions for chaining methods for a WebElementFacade selector using jBehave?

Comment: I don't understand how JBehave applies to this question.

Comment: If you're looking for a locator for that element, I would suggest an xpath of **//td[text()='Take these Directions']/following-sibling::/a[@title='Edit']**

Comment: jBehave is a requirement of my employer. It includes the WebElementFacade wrapper which allows the use of jQuery selectors as strings similar to css selectors, but not functions. I'll consider your xPath solution as advice along the lines of "you can't do that". Thank you, Bill Hileman.